# Intercepting all methods of the given assembly

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, aop

I'm trying to intercept all methods in the matching assemgly and log before and after invoke messages. The following code is failing to resolve the instance !!!

I have a IDemo interface which is implemented by Demo and Demo2 classes. Unity is configured in the config file. I'm just calling the LoadConfiguration method to load the unity. When I call container.Resolve(), it is not resolving the type.

***Please help***

### **Code File**

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity;
using Unity.Interception.InterceptionBehaviors;
using Unity.Interception.PolicyInjection.Pipeline;

namespace AopDemo
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var container = new UnityContainer();
                container.LoadConfiguration();
                var demo = container.Resolve<IDemo>();
                demo.DoSomething("123", 123);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public interface IDemo
    {
        void DoSomething(string message, int number);
    }

    public class Demo : IDemo
    {
        public Demo() { }

        public void DoSomething(string message, int number)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Demo - Doing Something !!! | message = {message}, number = {number}");
        }
    }

    public class AopInterceptionBehavior : IInterceptionBehavior
    {
        public bool WillExecute => true;
        public IEnumerable<Type> GetRequiredInterfaces() => Type.EmptyTypes;
        public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Before Invoking the method");
            var result = getNext().Invoke(input, getNext);
            Console.WriteLine("After Invoking the method");
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

### **Configuration File**

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Unity.Configuration" />
  </configSections>
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <sectionExtension type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Configuration.InterceptionConfigurationExtension, Unity.Interception.Configuration" />
    <container>
      <extension type="Interception" />
      <register type="IMatchingRule" mapTo="NamespaceMatchingRule">
        <constructor>
          <param name="namespaceName" value="AopDemo.*" />
        </constructor>
        <interceptor type="InterfaceInterceptor"/>
        <interceptionBehavior type="AopDemo.AopInterceptionBehavior, AopDemo" />
      </register>
    </container>
  </unity>
</configuration>
```

### **Error Message :**

[image]

Comment: Did you get that code working without interception? (Interface with two implementations looks suspicious...)

Comment: But you didn't register implementation for your `IDemo`, what should container resolve?

Comment: @Evk I'm trying to register all types under the name space "AopDemo.*".  If I register specific type and explicit interceptor, it works, but I want it in this way so that I can intercept all types.

Comment: But in your case you have 2 types `Demo` and `Demo2` implementing the same interface. Which one of them you want to be resolved when you call `Resolve<IDemo>`?

Comment: @EVk ,Ok I get it, I have only one class `Demo` which implements `IDemo`. My intent is , image you have a namespace with N number types. I want to intercept each and every type methods of the given namespace.

Comment: You can intercept only types registered in container, so you still have to register them, for example using conventions (`container.RegisterTypes(...)`)

Comment: Please refer this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507490(v=pandp.30).aspx), I followed this  and got stuck with the section "Configuring Policy Injection Policies", when I can register and intercept types via config file than doing in code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166227/discussion-between-karthik-d-v-and-evk).